# sharepoint 2010 - dynamically load web part (in web part zone) using jquery/ajax from link/button

Tags: web-part, jquery, ajax

i would like to have a link, when clicked loads a web part (for example list view web part) that retains its user config. therefore it needs to be a in a web part zone, personalizable and retain its personalization from previous visits.

my actual scenario is i have an app that has nav/tabs down the left hand side, when each tab is clicked it shows a hidden div to the right with the content relating to the clicked tab.

each div/content has different types of data, some divs will have custom web parts/controls and other will have out of the box ones. These need to be loaded without post backs as there is a lot of content on each div and i would rather not pre-load all in hidden divs.

just want to clarify, its not IN the web part i want to load data.. its the web part itself.

Comment: How did it go ? Please shae your results.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a page for each tab and then load that page into an IFrame when the corresponding tab is clicked.